# dyld: Symbol not found: _vmnet_shared_interface_name_key en el emulador Android Studio con macOS

Tags: android-studio, macos

Llevo un tiempo usando Android Studio 2020.3.1 para Mac (high sierra 10.13.6) sin problemas hasta que de repente el emulador dejó de funcionar y a dar un mensaje de que el proceso terminó.

Creo que he hecho prácticamente todas las soluciones que encontré en internet e incluso he restaurado el sistema y realizado una instalación limpia y nada.
Al abrirlo desde el terminal me dice esto:

```
*iMac:tools softegui$ ./emulator -avd Galaxy_Nexus_API_24
dyld: Symbol not found: _vmnet_shared_interface_name_key
  Referenced from: /Users/softegui/Library/Android/sdk/tools/../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386 (which was built for Mac OS X 11.1)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/vmnet.framework/Versions/A/vmnet
 in /Users/softegui/Library/Android/sdk/tools/../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
Abort trap: 6*
```

He buscado acerca de este error pero no encuentro nada que me resuelva.
Podrían ayudarme ?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La solución que me funcionó fue instalar [una versión anterior del emulador (30.7.3)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_x64-7425822.zip) y el proceso lo hice sustituyendo todos los archivos de la carpeta `emulator` que está dentro del sdk por los descargados menos `package.xml` y el emulador ahora me funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

#### Actualiza a macOS Catalina.

Después de actualizar a Emulator 30.9.5 en High Sierra, no pude iniciar ninguno de mis emuladores / AVD.

Intenté varias cosas, pero finalmente tuve que actualizar completamente a Catalina antes de que la versión requerida de `vmnet` estuviera en el sistema.

Una vez que hice eso, las cosas funcionaron.

Si no puede actualizar a Catalina, recomendaría degradar su emulador a una versión anterior y permanecer allí.

Una cosa que odio es que no hay un registro de cambios o notas de lanzamiento para algunas / la mayoría de las versiones del emulador. Ridículo.

### English

#### Upgrade to macOS Catalina.

After upgrading to Emulator 30.9.5 on High Sierra I was unable to start any of my emulators/AVDs.

I tried a number of things but ultimately, I had to upgrade all the way to Catalina before the required version of `vmnet` was on the system.

Once I did that, things worked.

If you can't upgrade to Catalina, I would recommend downgrading your Emulator to an older version and staying there.

One thing that I hate is that there are is no change-log or release notes for some/most of the emulator versions. Ridiculous.

Comment: Es SO en español, traduce la respuesta.

Comment: @Bicho Adicional. Lo siento, hablo inglés.